# What is the effect of stress on inflammation

Tags: stress, inflammation, anti-inflammatory, cortisol, meditation

People are advised to practice mindfulness meditation / breathing techniques for stress reduction which is considered to indirectly help with chronic inflammatory diseases also such as allergies, autoimmune diseases e.t.c. (in the long run).

On the other hand the medical prescription for the same (the above inflammatory diseases - arthritis, allergy, auto immune diseases) happens to be corticosteroid which contains cortisol- the stress hormone itself.

Is it not contradictory here? Of so what is the effect of stress and its hormones on inflammation?

P.S. Pardon me if there's any mistake here since I am not from medicine background. But I was a bit curious seeing this irony here.

Comment: Who prescribes corticosteroids for stress reduction? Who manages inflammation with mindful meditation and breathing techniques? I think you're making unfounded assumptions here.

Comment: No I meant corticosteroids are sometimes prescribed for allergies, auto immune diseases , rheumatoid arthritis. 
What I meant was that these inflammatory  issues are considered to stress related but still stress hormone is prescribed. I have edited the question now to make it more precise.

Comment: Who says allergies, auto-immune diseases and arthritis are stress related? This is the assumption you're making I think is unfounded. Your question would be greatly improved if you provided a supporting reference for this idea.

Comment: @CareyGregory Here's 1 such refernce to a study :-
https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/fullarticle/2685155
Another paper:-
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3264048/
And another
https://www.mdpi.com/1422-0067/22/5/2773

Comment: Please edit your question and put these links in the question, not just in comments. No one should have to read comments to understand your question.